# How to prevent "cost attacks" on AWS?

Tags: attack-prevention

Ok, so I'm using AWS and with a serverless architecture, it's very practical since AWS Lambda will run functions as microsservices and I don't have to deal with servers.

Not only that, but it's also auto-scalable, and they charge in this 'pay-as-you-go' format. Everything seems good, but...

Well, thinking in terms of security and possible attacks, I can imagine one type of attack where it's not necessarily a DDoS, but an attacker would just repetitively request data from my servers from multiple clients spread throughout a month (so it won't trigger API rate limits), so that my costs will increase drastically (because of pay-as-you-go + auto scaling) and essentially leaving me with a $10.000 bill at the end of the month.

I understand the term "cost attack" probably doesn't exist yet, but it can become more common as services move to serverless environments (AWS, Google Cloud, Azure, etc.)

Ideas on how to deal with it or prevent it?

Comment: I think cost attack is a very good term. Is there a way to distinguish valid and cost attack use? I'd assume it could be very hard.

Comment: This is not just an issue with server-less architectures, but is an attack model that has existed since the early days of the Internet.  The oldest attacks I can think of are when attackers would maliciously drive up bandwidth-bills by repeatedly downloading very large files.

Comment: I believe the correct term for this is DoW as opposed to the common DoS. The W stands for wallet.

Comment: "AWS allows you to set budgets (so your services would shut down instead of getting a $10k bill at the end of the month)," - there's no built-in budget feature of Amazon which results in shutting down services. One can program it manually though.

Comment: @Xander It seems we're going full circle

Answer (score 32, accepted):

AWS allows you to set budgets, and alarms based on your current rate of spending. Those would be useful to control your spending. In theory, you could also set billing-based automation to start scaling down services to avoid a $10k bill at the end of the month.

[AWS Budgets Tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-budgets/)

If your spending alarms go off, then you'd take a look and see why your costs are abnormal this month and determine what needs to be done to mitigate the attack. At that time, your actions will depend on what's driving your costs up.

It may be difficult to differentiate whether the costs are legitimate use or an attack. Following standard threat modelling practices will help you to identify parts of your application susceptible to this type of attack. In particular, try to limit the ability of unauthenticated users to access parts of the application that are resource intensive.

Comment: "try to limit the ability of unauthenticated users to access parts of the application that are resource intensive" - I like this. Do you know if unauthenticated calls that are denied by the API gateway count as traffic usage?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the specific service. That advice is more of a general security principle that helps to prevent any kind of Denial of Service attack. A cost attack is still DoS, except in this case the resource they're using up is your bank account. 

Comment: To provide a more specific example, if you're using Lambda, try to exit as quickly as possible if the user is not logged in. Don't even make a database call if it can be avoided.

Comment: You can actually use AWS cognito to authenticate and check, so you don't even write a custom lambda for auth, I'm just not sure if these calls stack up in the costs. Also, minimally, one would have to serve a login page through S3.

Comment: Isn't it the case that AWS Budgets only allow notifications but don't allow the scenario whereby "your services would shut down instead of getting a 10k bill ..."?

Comment: @RonaldMonson Ah. Would you look at that? Looks like you're right. That doesn't come out of the box. You could set CloudWatch alarms to start scaling/removing services if you approach your budget, but you're right. They don't seem to let your set a hard limit on spend.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect that AWS budgets can't set a hard limit.

Comment: Yes, apparently it is too difficult to do and goes against the "AWS philosophy" (I would have thought that if you can manually remove services then you can in principle automate this but there you go).